# How do I add a Mass Action for exporting to CSV with a custom admin grid?

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, grid

I followed this tutorial to create a custom module:
http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/

Now I want to add the ability to check mark specific rows and export just those to CSV. What is the best approach?

Here is what I have in the Grid.php:

```
 protected function _prepareMassaction() {

    $this->setMassactionIdField('increment_id');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('picklist_order_grid');  //html name of checkbox
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('export', array(
        'label'=> __('Export Selected'),
        'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/*/exportSelectedPicklistCsv'),   //an action defined in the controller
        'selected' => 'selected',
        'confirm' => __('Are you sure?')
    ));

return $this;

}
```

Which calls this function in the controller:

```
public function exportSelectedPicklistCsvAction()
{
    $fileName = 'picklist.csv';
    $grid = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('kevando_picklist/adminhtml_sales_order_grid');
    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $grid->getCsvFile());
}
```

This `exportSelectedPicklistCsvAction()` function works fine when I have export all the visible items, but not the ones which are check marked.

Any type of help or other SO links are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php

```
/**
 * Cancel selected orders
 */
public function massCancelAction()
{
    $orderIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids', array());
    $countCancelOrder = 0;
    $countNonCancelOrder = 0;
    foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
       ...
```

`$orderIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids', array());` contain all the checkbox ids you selected. So you need to use the ids as a filter in `'kevando_picklist/adminhtml_sales_order_grid'`

Comment: Thanks, this is a great start. What is the best way to filter the collection in the grid? I can't think of a way to do it that doesn't effect the grid every other time it gets prepared.

Comment: What i would recommend is to accept this question, then post a new question "how to filter by id" and add exportSelectedPicklistCsvAction() and your grid code

Comment: ;P And add a link to the new question .....